# How do I access a WPF UserControl's child control exposed as DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

The question has been asked before, but I didn't find a satisfying answer.
Say you have a `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestShowUserControl.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestShowUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="200">

<d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>

<DockPanel>
    <Label x:Name="lblCaption" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Caption"/>
    <TextBox Text="Hi there"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The `Label` control is exposed through a `DependencyProperty` like this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    #region DependencyProperties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCaptionControlProperty = DependencyProperty
    .Register(nameof(MyCaptionControl),
        typeof(Label),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public Label MyCaptionControl
    {
        get { return (Label)GetValue(MyCaptionControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCaptionControlProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyCaptionControl = lblCaption;
    }
}
```

How can I do the following:

```
<local:UserControl1 MyCaptionControl.Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

If not possible, is there another way to do it so in XAML?
Please note that I want to use the Label as if I have declare it myself locally and that I want to be able to bind its content to a ViewModel as necessary. Nonetheless, having to expose the `Style` could be an alternative of no better solution is possible.

Comment: I don't see why you can't write `<local:UserControl1 MyCaptionControl....`

Comment: Also I don't see why you don't write `public Label MyCaptionControl => lblCaption;`

Comment: Because it simple doesn't work. Have you tried yourself Bizhan?

Comment: Compiler says `MyCaptionControl is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.`

Comment: You can't do this, i.e. setting a property of the `Label` returned by the `MyCaptionControl` property, in XAML: `MyCaptionControl.Visibility="Collapsed"`. You will have to add a `Visibility` property to your control and then bind or set the `Label` in the control to this one.

Comment: Thank you @mm8. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. As you can imagine, It doesn't make much sense to have to wrap every single property.

Comment: @cneves: It kind of does when you define a control that "hides" the inner controls.

Comment: @mm8: Not quite. The purpose of the `UserControl` isn't hiding, but to group and reuse. Say I want a `TextBox` with a Caption. Don't you think it's better to have your own `UserControl` with docking properties instead of having to implement it every single time?

Comment: @cneves: Possibly depending on the exact requirements, but then it's not a `TextBox` any longer but a control with a different set of properties. The consumer of the control isn't supposed to know that it uses a `TextBox` under the hood.

Comment: @mm8: I've answered the question base on your assertive comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @mm8 at the comments, the technical issue isn't relevant because the approach wasn't the right one. The purpose of a `UserControl` is to provide a reusable interface for a certain task. The consumer of the `UserControl` shouldn't be aware of its components, as they can vary in the future. Now the so called `MyCaptionControl` is of type `Label` but it can be a `TextBlock` or whatever. Therefore the question is considered answered.